# Conflicting with parent property "description" in Swift

Tags: swift, nsobject

I'm using **EVNetworkningObject** of **EVReflection** library to serialize or deserialize json response from web service. It means I can't change the property name "description" as "description_" or something like that. At the same time, backend will not change their response property for me. How possibly can I fix this error?

[image]

The error message says

> Getter for 'description' with Objective-C selector 'description'
>   conflicts with getter for 'description' from superclass 'NSObject'
>   with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: Use a struct or use `Codable`. If `EVReflection` is not able to map property names it's unqualified anyway.

Comment: @vadian, how? I'm new to iOS.

Comment: plus, it's not about EVReflection problem. It's NSObject problem.

Comment: All third party libraries to (de)serialize JSON became obsolete in favor of `Codable` in Swift 4+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vadian suggested in comments, I decided to use `Codable` protocol instead of `EVReflection` as `Codable` is way easy to use. I read this [link](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/) for `Codable` and [this video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpTNaBUFkno) for parsing json data.

Answer (score 5):

`description` is a property of the protocol named `NSObjectProtocol` of `NSObject`.

```
public var description: String { get }
```

So you can't initiate any variable with the **same name** in any `NSObject` subclasses.

For more please visit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418746-description.

Please try either by initiating the variable with **different names** or by implementing with `Codable` protocol of what `@vadian` suggested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The by far easiest work-around with be to rename the property. Ex: `var announcementDescription : String?`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using JSON decodable for getting JSON data. if so , You don't need to make your super class of type `NSObject`. The reason you are getting this error is because the name conflicts with getter for 'description' from superclass 'NSObject'. So make `EVNetworking`(which is your super class) object  a class which conforms to only decodable protocol and not a class of type NSObject.